# NSUserDefaults returns swift array [String] instead of Set<String>

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm storing a set of strings (`Set<String>`) into a `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` and when retrieving back the object, it comes back as an array of strings instead of a set.

This block works, as I'm recreating the array as a NSSet

```
if let products = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("products") as? [String] {

   // recreate the array into a NSSet / Set
   if let productSet = NSSet(array: products) as? Set<NSObject> {
     // now it's a set 
   }

}
```

However, it's not possible to get the object directly as a swift Set:

```
if let products = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("products") as? Set<String> {
   // will not cast into Set<String>
}
```

I assume `NSUserDefaults` coverts set into an array internally? Is there a way to receive the items as a set and not an array?

Comment: According to the documentation, a user defaults object must be an instance or a combination of NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. How did you store a *Set*?

Comment: Convert anything in NSData and on retrieval  type cast it to whatever you want when originally converted

Comment: `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Set(["a", "b"]), forKey: "products")` throws a runtime exception. Without seeing how you *set* the defaults it is impossible to give a (helpful) answer.

Comment: I'm getting the data as a JSON object and store it with NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(response)

Comment: JSON objects have arrays, dictionaries, strings, numbers, *but no sets*.

Comment: ah, makes sense now. I assumed NSUserDefaults will cast an object to either a set or an array, as long as it's a collection of items of a specific type

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer : No

`NSUserDefaults` cannot store sets. It's documented that way and it's because of the limitations of the format used to store the data on disk.

<strike>If saving a set works for you and automatically converts it to an array, you're actually lucky as I don't think this is a documented behavior and it should just throw an error.</strike>
EDIT : It doesn't work and you should not try it.

The best practice is to convert it to an array before saving and convert it back to a set after retrieving. You could also write a category on `NSUserDefaults` that does that automatically. Here is an example with objective-C :

```
//
//  NSUserDefaults+SetAdditions.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSUserDefaults (SetAdditions)

- (NSSet *)setForKey:(NSString *)defaultName;
- (void)setSet:(NSSet *)set forKey:(NSString *)defaultName;

@end


//
//  NSUserDefaults+SetAdditions.m
//

#import "NSUserDefaults+SetAdditions.h"

@implementation NSUserDefaults (SetAdditions)

- (NSSet *)setForKey:(NSString *)defaultName
{
    NSArray *array = [self arrayForKey:defaultName];
    if (array) {
        return [NSSet setWithArray:array];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (void)setSet:(NSSet *)set forKey:(NSString *)defaultName
{
    if (set) {
        [self setObject:[set allObjects] forKey:defaultName];
    } else {
        [self setObject:nil forKey:defaultName];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: As stated above, saving a set does *not* work and does *not* automatically convert to an array.

Comment: @MartinR Edited my answer. That's what I thought too.